# How to add legend/gradient in Folium Heat Map?

Tags: python, gradient, legend, heatmap, folium

I am creating a heat map using Folium.My data contains 3 columns one is category, lat and long. The lat-long points are categorized into 3 categories like A, B, and C.
I am able to plot the heat map using folium, but I need to add the legend showing the color difference between the points.I need to mark points into 3 different colors based on the category.

I am attaching the sample code which for your reference.Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
from folium import plugins
from folium.plugins import HeatMap
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster
import pandas as pd

map = folium.Map(location=[lat, long],zoom_start =12) 
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
# List comprehension to make out list of lists
heat_data = [[row['LAT'],row['LONG'],] for index, row in data.iterrows()]
# Plot it on the map
HeatMap(heat_data).add_to(map)
# Display the map
map
map.save('C:\Temp\map2.html')
```

Answer (score 8):

*Below is the solution and it's based on the answer of @Alexei Novikov
Code below is more complete*

```
import branca.colormap
from collections import defaultdict
import folium
import webbrowser
from folium.plugins import HeatMap 

map_osm = folium.Map(llocation=[35,110],zoom_start=1)

steps=20
colormap = branca.colormap.linear.YlOrRd_09.scale(0, 1).to_step(steps)
gradient_map=defaultdict(dict)
for i in range(steps):
    gradient_map[1/steps*i] = colormap.rgb_hex_str(1/steps*i)
colormap.add_to(map_osm) #add color bar at the top of the map

HeatMap(data1,gradient = gradient_map).add_to(map_osm) # Add heat map to the previously created map

file_path = r"C:\\test.html"
map_osm.save(file_path) # Save as html file
webbrowser.open(file_path) # Default browser open
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to create a dictionary with colormap values

```
steps = 20
color_map=cm.linear.PuBu.scale(0,1).to_step(steps)

gradient_map=defaultdict(dict)
for i in range(steps):
    gradient_map[1/steps*i] = color_map.rgb_hex_str(1/steps*i)
```

and then use it as the gradient for the HeatMap.

```
HeatMap(heat_data, gradient = gradient_map)
```

Comment: How is definite defaultdict(dict)

Comment: What is `cm` equal to in this case?

Comment: Just figured it out: `import branca.colormap as cm`